How to display an approximate location?
On a Drupal 11 website, I installed the Address and Geolocation Field modules.
I don't know if these are the most relevant modules for my project
I want the user to enter their address when creating their account and for it to be geocoded.
The problem is that the address is specified with the street and the number.
What I want is to have an approximate address (an area) with only the postal code, the city and the country.
The goal is that when I display users on a View page (a map), it is not possible to locate them precisely.
In short, I only want the city on the map and the coordinates.
Here is an example:

